# Joining columns of two queries

Tags: google-visualization

My full code is as below @ http://jsbin.com/ciroy/8/edit

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>~Khanz~</title>
   </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
     google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
         var options = {
         title: 'Electrolyser Data',
         legend: {position: 'bottom'},  
         hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, format: 'MMM d', gridlines: {count: '31'}}
       };
   var data; var data0; var data1;  
   var query0 = new google.visualization.Query(
       'http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoTfmfAJUVoSdGRIVklheHdIS1ZCaHQ1MllvM19hUWc&sheet=MonthlyAvg-A');
   var query1 = new google.visualization.Query(
        'http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoTfmfAJUVoSdDhKOWRGRDNyeks1aF9jSFpHcmFfblE&sheet=MonthlyAvg-B');    
   function drawChart() { 
     query0.setQuery('select D,E limit 7');
     query0.send(handleQueryResponse0);
     query1.setQuery('SELECT D,E limit 7');
     query1.send(handleQueryResponse1);
   }


   function handleQueryResponse0(response0) {
     if (response0.isError()) {
       alert('Error in query: ' + response0.getMessage() + ' ' + response0.getDetailedMessage());
       return;
     }

  var data0 = response0.getDataTable(); 
     var table0 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table0.draw(data0);
var chart0 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart0.draw(data0, options);
  } 
   function handleQueryResponse1(response1) {
     if (response1.isError()) {
       alert('Error in query: ' + response1.getMessage() + ' ' + response1.getDetailedMessage());
       return;
     }

  var data1 = response1.getDataTable(); 
     var table1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div2'));
      table1.draw(data1);
     var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization2'));
   chart1.draw(data1, options);
 //data = new google.visualization.data.join(data1,data0,'full',[0],[1],[1]);     
    // table1.draw(data1);
  }    

   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   </script>
 </head>
 <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization" style="width: 500px;height: 500px"></div>
   <div id="visualization2" style="width: 500px;height: 500px"></div>
   <div id='table_div' style="width: 600px;"></div>
   <div id='table_div2' style="width: 600px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am able so far to properly visualize data from two different sources however what I need is to join the data from two different queries. In the case shown `query0` & `query1` each pull **two** columns however the first column **Date** is common to both. I want to have a final data composed of **three** columns e.g the first **Date** (common) the second **Kf** of Electrolyser-A & the third **Kf** of Electrolyser-B. Finally draw a ColumnChart & a Table to show side by side comparison of both Electrolysers. I am unable to do it using something like

`data = new google.visualization.data.join(data1,data0,'full',[0],[1],[1]);`

It should have compared the first column & replicate the second column from data0 & data1. Is my comprehension wrong?
Secondly can someone optimise the code so that `function handleQueryResponse` need not to be defined for each query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `data0` and `data1` in global scope and then create local scope variants of each in your `handleQueryResponse` functions, so while `data0` exists in `handleQueryResponse1`, it is `null`.  Even if you used the global-scope variables, this wouldn't solve your problem, as it is entirely possible that `query1` would return before `query0`, and thus `data0` would still be null.

Try this approach instead:

```
function drawChart() {
    // create an array containing one false for each query
    var ready = [false, false];
    // create an array to hold the DataTables
    var dataArray = [];
    function handleQueryResponse(response, index) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query ' + index + ': ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }
        ready[index] = true;
        dataArray[index] = response.getDataTable();
        var allReady = true;
        // check if all the queries have returned
        for (var i = 0; i < ready.length; i++) {
            if (!ready[i]) {
                allReady = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if all the queries have returned, draw the charts and tables
        if (allReady) {
            var data = new google.visualization.data.join(data[1], data[0], 'full', [0], [1], [1]);
            var options = {
                title: 'Electrolyser Data',
                legend: {position: 'bottom'},
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Date',
                    titleTextStyle: {
                        color: 'red'
                    },
                    format: 'MMM d',
                    gridlines: {
                        count: 31
                    }
                }
            };
            var tables = [];
            tables[0] = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div0'));
            tables[0].draw(dataArray[0]);
            tables[1] = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div1'));
            tables[1].draw(dataArray[1]);
            tables[2] = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div2'));
            tables[2].draw(data);

            var charts = [];
            charts[0] = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization0'));
            charts[0].draw(dataArray[0], options);
            charts[1] = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization1'));
            charts[1].draw(dataArray[1], options);
        }
    }

    var query0 = new google.visualization.Query('http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoTfmfAJUVoSdGRIVklheHdIS1ZCaHQ1MllvM19hUWc&sheet=MonthlyAvg-A');
    var query1 = new google.visualization.Query('http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoTfmfAJUVoSdDhKOWRGRDNyeks1aF9jSFpHcmFfblE&sheet=MonthlyAvg-B');
    query0.setQuery('select D,E limit 7');
    query0.send(function (response) {
        handleQueryResponse(response, 0);
    });
    query1.setQuery('SELECT D,E limit 7');
    query1.send(function (response) {
        handleQueryResponse(response, 1);
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: Thanks sir, for making me understand. I would now request you to solve the second part of my problem related to `query joining`

Comment: Your join statement is almost correct, you just need to fix the join columns parameter.  It takes an array of arrays of column indices to match.  If you want to match column 0 in each DataTable, you should pass `[[0, 0]]`, not `[0]`: `data = new google.visualization.data.join(data1, data0, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);`.

Comment: Thanks sir, your are great. Plz check the final output here http://jsbin.com/ciroy/15/edit however the problem i am now facing is that the **combined** data is alphabetically arranged which appears quiet awkward for date column. I am not able to format my first column from text to date i have tried using `dateFormatter` API

Comment: The queries must be returning strings instead of Dates if that is the case.  Check your spreadsheet to confirm that the date columns are actually dates in the spreadsheet and not text columns.

Comment: Thank you sir all set now, you made me a happy process engineer http://jsbin.com/ciroy/22/